# Create a SIN number validator

Tags: c

I am creating a C program which tests if a user has entered a valid SIN number. Here is what I have done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int num1;
    printf("Enter your SIN number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
}
```

SIN number is a 9 digit long number. To see if it is valid, I want to multiply the SIN number like this:

```
add SIN number with 121 212 121.
123 456 789
121 212 121
```

How would I do this part in C programming language?

Comment: This will not even compile. Provide a [mcve] and explain what you want to accomplish. Do not forget to explain what a "SIN" is, there are more countries in the world than yours.

Comment: The results expected to be?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Insurance_Number#Validation multiplication of each digit?

Comment: Yes we  need to multiply each digit. It is not add, I made a mistake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1[9];
    int vnum[9] = {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1};
    printf("Enter your SIN number(Hyphen(-) isn't included): \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i){
        if(1!=scanf("%1d", &num1[i])){//input one digit
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i){
        int mod, mul = num1[i] * vnum[i];
        sum +=  mul > 9 ? ((mod = mul % 9) ? mod : 9) : mul;
    }
    if(sum % 10 == 0)
        puts("valid");
    else
        puts("invalid");
    return 0;
}
```